# Its possible create a general channel?

Tags: discussion

Hi computer graphics comunity, my question it look seem a suggestion:

Its possible create a General channel on the chat to talk with computer graphics members, because sometimes the begginer user in computer graphics dont know how create a question, or is not necessary create one, i was watching many question that the users ask or something like this: "what algorithm can i use?"

as well this channel should be util to get to know each other a little more.

thanks...

Comment: I think "the cornell box" is the chat you are looking for. It's decription says "General discussion for http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com ". Maybe we should rename it to make the purpose a little bit clearer. Feel free to fill the chat with some live. I will join if i find the time :) However, with your 100+ rep, you also have the ability to create new chat rooms if you want to discuss a certain topic in an extra chat.

Comment: @wychmaster thank you, but in this "the cornell box" chat  there are a Boot, this Boot may  interrupt the human conversation

Comment: @wychmaster can i create a new chat without a Boot please? I would like to make it official so that all users can discuss topics of interest.

Comment: I am not sure if it is really a good idea to have 2 general discussion chats. With the "bot" you probably mean the news feed that creates a new message every time a new question is asked. We can deactivate that but I think it is not really a problem. In my perception, the issue is simply that nobody uses the chat. Therefore it looks like it is flooded with automatic messages but this is hardly the case with our average 1.6 questions a day. So let's try the one that already exists first. I will try to visit the chat more often. Maybe we can resurrect it together.

Comment: @wychmaster thanks so much! ok i will be in chat very often